# Added a new user on Ubuntu, set password not working?

Tags: users, group

I created a new user:

```
$ sudo useradd -m Ari -p pass123
```

But when I went to login it said the password was incorrect, I know it's correct because I saved the command line log as a text file.

Other than that, at the same time I also created a group:

```
$ sudo groupadd testgroup1
```

and added the new account to it:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G testgroup1 Ari
```

Why can't a log in?

Comment: On Ubuntu, as in Debian, you're supposed to use `adduser` and `addgroup`. That takes care of Stuff for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `-p` option is looking for an encrypted password:

> -p, --password PASSWORD
>
> > The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the
> >                password.

```
Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will
be visible by users listing the processes.

You should make sure the password respects the system's password policy.
```

You should use the following to change the password:

```
sudo passwd Ari
```

---

In order to use the `-p` option you must first encrypt the password.  You can use some of the methods mentioned [here](https://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/generating-passwords-using-crypt3/) such as:

```
$ mkpasswd
Password:
1puqSPGTnyi5o
$ sudo useradd -m Ari -p 1puqSPGTnyi5o
```

Note the `mkpasswd` utility is included in the `whois` package which can be obtained through apt

Comment: What would be the correct way to do it from the terminal? `$ sudo useradd -m Ari pass123` or just creating the user then doing as you suggest?

Comment: The preferred and safe way is to set the password separately with `passwd` but I have updated the question to include instructions on encrypting a password for use with `useradd -p`

Comment: ***Don't*** use `openssl passwd`, and especially not with `-crypt`. It uses the [obsolete DES-based _crypt_ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(Unix)), which among other things is limited to only 8-characters passwords (and 2-character salts). The openssl on my system does support the MD5-based  hash (`$1$`), but not the newer SHA2-based hashes (`$5$` and `$6$`), which are the ones commonly used on Linux-systems.

Comment: If you need to batch change passwords, use `chpasswd`. By default it runs the change through PAM, so you get a) the same hashing as with `passwd`, and b) the passwords updated to whatever it is your system actually uses (in case you have e.g. LDAP). It also does support e.g. `-c SHA512`, too, if you do need to bypass PAM.